# January 2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

This community last had moderators appointed in 2013, so it's been a while... In addition to that, the moderator team has reached out requesting extra hands on deck.

Since moderators were last appointed in this community, we've started and "graduated" and experiment: and pro-tem moderators [are now elected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332180/208518), just like "regular" moderators. As such, we're looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere in January 2020. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in January '20.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

**UPDATE:** Because of the upcoming holidays, [elections are planned on February 24, 2020](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332/announcing-a-pro-tempore-moderator-election). This means that this post will remain open until then.

Comment: Could you please make [elections] a synonym of [election] on this meta site?

Comment: Yup! Done, @Nic :)

Answer (score 5):

I would also be interested in running for moderator. I'm quite active on the site and interested in helping to keep it growing and running smoothly.

Comment: That's great! You've been very helpful guiding new people and flagging problematic posts. I think you would make a great moderator.

Comment: I've definitely noticed how active and helpful you are on this site, and I want to say that I appreciate it.

Comment: I agree with THelper - I'm really glad you've put yourself forward.

Comment: nominations are open now : https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election - please do nominate yourself

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I would be willing to run for a moderator position on Sustainability.SE.

Although I don't have particularly high rep here, I do try to ask high quality questions and write good answers when I know something about the subject matter. I don't have prior experience being a ♦Moderator on the StackExchange network, but I've served other communities (web fora and Facebook groups) in a moderator role previously.

I believe that this site specifically (and StackExchange, more generally) is fulfilling an important mission to help provide people with quality information and a higher level of discourse in an arena that often seems to lack it. It would be an honour to play a role in the continuing development of this community.

Comment: That's great! From your profile I see you have a lot of experience with the StackExchange platform.

Comment: Thank you! Good to have you in the running

Comment: nominations are open now : https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election - please do nominate yourself

Answer (score 3):

Even though I've only been a member of Sustainability SE for about 1 month and just barely scraped into the 300 rep requirement, I'd like to run for moderator as well.

I'm currently a mod on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/28182/robotnik?tab=profile) so I believe I have the relevant Stack Exchange community and SE mod-tool experience.

I was quite excited when I found this site and over the past month I've been delving into some of our older questions here while also asking some of my own. Sustainable Living has been a passion of mine for years, and I'm currently in a position of being able to finally implement some of my personal long-term goals (such as solar and grey-water capture and filtration), as well as potentially submitting to (and working with) my local council on sustainability practices on a larger scale.

I'll take a moment to wish the other nominees the best of luck - it's a good crowd, I feel everyone here would make great moderators in their own right. Even if I'm not one of them, I look forward to continue to learn and grow along with this site.

Comment: That's great! It would be wonderful to have an experienced moderator join us.

Comment: Just a heads' up that with our recent [graduation](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/398/3379), there will be another round of moderator elections coming up. It would be great if you could nominate yourself again!

Comment: @LShaver thanks for the heads up! 

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 2020-01-14:** Due to yesterdays [firing of two highly competent and popular community managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342039/172266), I am no longer willing to take on any additional moderator roles within the Stack Exchange network.

<s>I would run if and only if nobody better placed does.</s>

My activity on Sustainable Living has been moderate, but I am an active moderator over at Earth Science Stack Exchange, which has some overlap with Sustainable Living.

**Edit 2019-12-03:** As things are standing now I would withdraw (i.e. not run) and endorse LShaver, who has been a much more active member of the Sustainable Living Stack Exchange than myself and therefore knows the community better than I do.

**Edit 2019-12-13:** I might run after all depending on the exact circumstances.

Comment: That's great! It would be wonderful to have an experienced moderator join us.

Comment: Hi! You said that "*I would run if and only if nobody better placed does.*". After your post 2 other people expressed their interest in becoming a mod, so I was wondering if that means that you will withdraw? Or do you still want to participate in the election?

Comment: @THelper I will probably withdraw, question edited, I think LShaver is better placed than myself.  I've also replied with a similar response to a [similar request on Space SE](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1412/33) where there I may be relatively better placed, and I'm not currently interested in being a moderator on *three* sites.

Comment: I do hope you will keep yourself in the running, as there will be more than one opening.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Oh, I see.  That may change the equation.  I will think about it more.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers See update.  Due to recent events, I don't want to do this anymore.

Comment: @gerrit I understand.

Comment: @gerrit just in case you're interested in running again, nominations are open now : https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Thanks for the link. Let me see who else nominates first.

Comment: Just a heads' up that with our recent [graduation](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/398/3379), there will be another round of moderator elections coming up. I'm not sure if you're still interested, but it would be great if you wanted to nominate yourself!

Comment: Pinging you one last time... there are just 3 hours left for nominations. If we don't have at least four candidates (we have three now) then the election won't be competitive, as there are three slots, so not a full "graduation" election.

Comment: @LShaver Looks like there is another week for nominations?  I'll think it over and may nominate myself again tonight.

Comment: Yes, since there weren't enough candidates the nomination period was extended. Thanks!