# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Sustainable Living Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **February 24, 2020** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on February 24, 2020, users can [nominate themselves](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On March 2, 2020, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on March 10, 2020.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

---

> **Note:** The election date was pushed back a month, due to some ongoing back-end work on the election mechanics, in order to automate some steps.

Comment: As a current mod on Arqade I believe I have the SE experience necessary to help moderate, but is there a minimum site-rep requirement for being considered for moderation? I've only recently discovered Sustainable Living SE but it's something I've been passionate about for years, and I wouldn't mind throwing my hat in the ring to help this site grow.

Comment: The sidebar [on the election page](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election/1) says `any community member in good standing with more than 300 reputation may nominate themselves`, @Robotnik. You still have a bit of time to get there, and are already halfway through :)

Comment: @Robotnik Congrats on reaching 300 reputation!

Comment: @THelper Thanks! With plenty of time to spare :)

Answer (score 6):

I am one of the moderators who will step down. As can be seen from our (public) [Site statistics](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/85) Sustainability.SE has been growing slowly but steadily and the library built here already seems to provide canonical answers to a large number of sustainability related questions (with several questions over 100k views).

In almost seven years(!) much has changed work- and family-wise and I have found it increasingly difficult to spend time here on the site, so I am looking forward to the new faces that will be able to make the site a better place and wish us all on the site continued success!

Comment: Thank you for all the work you did here on Sustainable Living! I know you are rather busy these days, but I hope to see you on the site occasionally.

Answer (score 6):

Like Earthliŋ , I'm stepping down too. It's been an honour to serve this community, and I hope that the new mods will take the site onto much greater things than I've been able to.

Comment: Thank you for all your work! You've written many great answers and I hope that you will continue to write more.

Comment: I notice you changed your handle and avatar -- any particular significance? From generic energy-related numbers to a specific number -- the [current CO2 concentration in ppm](https://www.co2.earth/)?

Comment: @LShaver 410 Gone is a http status code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors