# We graduated! Now what?

Tags: discussion, beta

As you may have seen a while back, [59 sites left beta in December 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/346823), and Sustainable Living is one of those sites.

The linked Meta.SE post goes into all the details, but essentially this means that because we've been around for a while and met some criteria used to define a "healthy" site, we are able to shed our "beta" status.

There are a couple of things that are changing as a result:

- The "beta" label has been removed from the site name
- Another round of moderator elections will take place shortly (stay tuned!)
- We're now eligible for the community ads program, which is a way to promote our site across the Stack Exchange network. When the program opens for 2022 we'll start a discussion here about whether to participate.

Thanks to everyone who has contributed here -- your questions, answers, and community moderation have made this possible.

Comment: [Question collection is now open for the upcoming election!](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/399/5864) Please submit any questions there that y'all would like to see answered by those who decide to nominate themselves in the election.